# How does this line of code negate a std::uint64_t value?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand what this code does. This is supposed to negate the coefficient `coeff` of type `uint64_t*` of a polynomial with coefficients modulus `modulus_value` of type `const uint64_t`:

```
std::int64_t non_zero = (*coeff != 0);
*coeff = (modulus_value - *coeff) & static_cast<std::uint64_t>(-non_zero);
```

What's up with the `& static_cast<std::uint64_t>(-non_zero)`? How does this negate anything?

The code is from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/6bfac481aae4057ea887d42eb0f24371e9b4c4f9/native/src/seal/util/polyarithsmallmod.h#L104).

Comment: That doesn't negate anything.  It masks it, forcing to zero if `non_zero` is `0`.  The negation happened at `modulus_value - *coeff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`non_zero` will be either `1` or `0`.

`-non_zero` will turn that into `-1` or `0`.

`static_cast<std::uint64_t>(-non_zero)` will tell the compiler to treat the signed number as unsigned, which will turn `0` into `0`, and `-1` into `0xffffffffffffffff`.

Then the bitwise AND will either clear all bits of `(modulus_value - *coeff)` (if `non_zero` is `0`) or keep all the bits of  `(modulus_value - *coeff)` as they are (i.e. it's a no-op really).

So the result assigned back to `*coeff` will be either `0` or `modulus_value - *coeff`.

It's equivalent to `(modulus_value - *coeff) * non_zero`. Or in shorter form `(modulus_value - *coeff) * !!*coeff`.

Answer (score 6):

This code is a branchless version of

```
if (*coeff) *coeff = (modulus_value - *coeff);
// else *coeff = *coeff;
```

The negation is `(modulus_value - *coeff)`.

The `& static_cast<std::uint64_t>(-non_zero)` implements the condition without a branch, and is totally unrelated to negation.

---

FWIW you're probably better off with the easy-to-understand `if` statement version.  Architectures with a "conditional MOV" will use it instead of a branch, and compilers for other architectures will almost invariably know how to optimize a conditional assignment to the branchless version.

---

Two other equivalent versions are:

```
*coeff = (*coeff) ? (modulus_value - *coeff) : (*coeff);
```

and

```
*coeff = (*coeff) ? (modulus_value - *coeff) : 0;
```

all of which are easier to understand for both humans and compilers than the version in the question.

Comment: @GSerg: If `*coeff` is zero, it is "changed" again to zero.  The `if` formulation is correct, as would be `*coeff = (*coeff) ? (modulus_value - *coeff) : 0;`

Comment: @GSerg: The useless write (and the false cache contention that comes with it) is the price of branchless code.  Some architectures have a "conditional MOV" instruction that is ideal for this scenario... but probably won't be generated from the prematurely optimized source code in the question.

Comment: Interestingly, all of GCC, Clang, and MSVC have trouble removing the branch in your answer's snippet, but all of them remove the branch in your comment's snippet with the unconditional assignment hinting them along. If one were looking to have a more readable branchless version, the comment version is probably the way to go. (I also happened to notice Clang and MSVC do generate a form of cmov for the question, but not GCC.)

Comment: @chris: Probably because avoiding or performing the useless write has important interplay with the language rules for data races.  Does the optimization happen if the "do nothing" else is added in, as shown in my edited answer?

Comment: Fair idea. It looks like they [still don't](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hMKWT93hz) with the `else` in there, which is very surprising to me.

Comment: @chris: Just FYI msvc doesn't have a `/O3` optimization level, and at `/O2` it does the same branching version as the other two compilers at `-O2` and `-O3`.  Probably because the compiler knows the branching version is better in isolation.

Comment: Yeah, I got confused for a minute and then found that I accidentally put /O3 when cloning compilers.

Comment: The real test would be in code eligible for auto-vectorization, where branchless is most needed.  Or with a GPGPU compiler targeting hardware where branches taken on only some shader units are super-expensive.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Agreed. In my opinion a pretty pointless and potentially self-defeating bit of optimization but I upvoted both question and this answer for what they taught me.  It's code like this that contributes to C++'s reputation as an inscrutable language but the fact that it allows such things to even be contemplated is why - after 25 years since first introduction - it is still my favourite language.